# How to make 3 group from ten matrices using k-means algorithm

Tags: matlab, matrix, k-means

I have 10 matrices like the following:

```
c1 = [1 428; 2 465; 3 513; 4 540];

c2 = [1 15292; 2 15438; 3 12201; 4 12321];

c3 = [1 5054; 2 2582; 3 2507];

c4 = [1 26602; 2 26708; 3 27178];

c5 = [1 191874; 2 191985; 3 192210; 4 192405];

c6 = [1 185704; 2 186012; 3 186964; 4 186820; 5 187446];

c7 = [1 65666; 2 65728; 3 65877; 4 65972; 5 66215; 6 66162];

c8 = [1 22427; 2 22524; 3 26163; 4 22720];

c9 = [1 26351; 2 26364; 3 26406; 4 26388];

c10 = [1 120188; 2 120256; 3 120411];
```

I have to write a code that groups these 10 matrices into `3` groups such as "big", "medium", and "small" according to their 2nd column using `kmeans`.
How can I do that?

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but ... are those in the code block your matrices? that is, you have 10 4x2 matrices and want to cluster them based on the second column? and did you miss the 4th row of the 10th one?

Comment: Anything you have tried? Where do you get the matrices from?

Comment: no no ,, not necessary that all matrices have same no. of rows here i gave just some of them. the actual order of each matrices are c1 is 11x2 , c2 is 23x2 ,c3 is 3x2 , c4 is 5x2 ,c5 is 19x2 , c6 is 17x2 , c7 is 16x2 , c8 is 5x2 , c9 is 19x2 and c10 is 14x2 .

Comment: these matrices are given to me.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way how to do it:

1. Turn all your 2nd column into a vector of its own:

   ```
   C = [c1(:,2);c2(:,2);c3(:,2);c4(:,2);c5(:,2);...
        c6(:,2);c7(:,2);c8(:,2);c9(:,2);c10(:,2)];
   ```

   If you expect to have more than those 10 matrices, consider not storing individual arrays but multidimensional matrices.
2. Call [`kmeans`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/kmeans.html) with the new vector `C` as input and tell it you want `3` clusters:

   ```
   [idx,~] = kmeans(C,3);
   ```
3. If you plot your result, you'll get the figure below:

   ```
   plot(C(idx==1,1),'r.','MarkerSize',12)
   hold on
   plot(C(idx==2,1),'b.','MarkerSize',12)
   plot(C(idx==3,1),'g.','MarkerSize',12)
   ```

[image: kmeans_vector]

**EDIT**

If you want to figure out which matrix belongs to which group, you can try the following approach. *However*, it is based on the assumption that the first matrix element is a characteristic value for that matrix. It will work, if all matrix elements would end up in the same group. Once your matrix elements cover a large range, this assumption will be invalid.

1. Set up your vector `C` to only contain one (here the first) element of the second column of each matrix:

   ```
   C = [c1(1,2);c2(1,2);c3(1,2);c4(1,2);c5(1,2);...
        c6(1,2);c7(1,2);c8(1,2);c9(1,2);c10(1,2)];
   ```
2. Again, call `kmeans` to determine groups:

   ```
   [idx,~] = kmeans(C,3);
   ```
3. Now, use [`find`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) to get the indexes of the index values associated with the groups. It is important to store these in a [`cell`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell.html) because you are likely to have a different amount of matrices per group:

   ```
   CLUSTER{1} = find(idx==1);
   CLUSTER{2} = find(idx==2);
   CLUSTER{3} = find(idx==3);
   ```

   The values stored in `CLUSTER` tell you which matrix number belongs to which group. `CLUSTER{1}` contains the numbers of the matrices that belong to the first group.
4. Finally, you can visualize which matrix belongs to which group by plotting:

   ```
   plot(CLUSTER{1},C(idx==1,1),'r.','MarkerSize',12)
   hold on
   plot(CLUSTER{2},C(idx==2,1),'b.','MarkerSize',12)
   plot(CLUSTER{3},C(idx==3,1),'g.','MarkerSize',12)
   ```

   This will give you a plot like this:

   [image]

   The values on the `x`-axis correspond to the matrix number. For example, matrix `7` and `10` belong to the *medium* group.

Comment: thanks Mr Schorsch .. but this is not what I want,, actually i need what matrices are belong to what group ,, means c1, c2 ,c9 belong to small group or c3, c7,c8 belong to medium group and c4,c5,c6,c10 belong to big group... so how could i do this?

Comment: @user2594167 See my edit. Is this helpful to you?

Comment: is there any possibility if i initialize three centroid of three group n then and then apply k-means algorithm. like CC1 = 1034;CC2 = 5058;
CC3 = 11129; where CC1  ,  CC2, CC3 are three centroid of three group..

Comment: @user2594167 I do not understand what you mean by that. How do you know the centroids in advance? What do you want to initialize? What should happen next?